# Identity Server 3 - Posted data for token endpoint not read

Tags: iis, identityserver3, production

I have a strange problem for an application I put in production.

The app is a Asp.net 4.7.2 Webapi protected by an embedded Identity Server 3 instance plus an instance of swagger for documentation.

I need only client authentication so I choose `client credential` as flow.

These are the main configuration data for the application.

```
new Client {
    ClientName = "GDPR Logger Client",
    Enabled = true,
    ClientId = "gdpr_logger",
    Flow = Flows.ClientCredentials,
    AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Reference,
    ClientSecrets = new List<Secret> {
        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
    },
    AllowedScopes = new List<string> {
        "write"
    },
    AccessTokenLifetime = 30
}

app.Map("/auth", auth => {
    var options = new IdentityServerOptions {
        SiteName = "GDPR LOGGER Authentication Server",
        SigningCertificate = LoadCertificate(),
        RequireSsl = true,
        Factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory()
            .UseInMemoryUsers(new List<InMemoryUser>())
            .UseInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
            .UseInMemoryScopes(Scopes.Get());
    };
    auth.UseIdentityServer(options);
});

private static X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate() {
    certificateFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RelativeCertPath"]);
    X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2();
    cert.Import(certificateFilePath, "GDPRLoggerCert",           X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
    return cert;}
```

In my local machine all work perfect, but as soon I put it on my server the Identity Server stop working.

When I try to get the access token for the client (with client_credentials flow) Identity Server respond me with `invalid_client` when I `POST` to `https://{my-server}/auth/connect/token` all data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content in the request `grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=gdpr_logger&client_secret=secret&scope=write`.

```
2018-11-20 09:14:20,035 [244] INFO  IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.TokenEndpointController - Start token request
2018-11-20 09:14:20,066 [244] DEBUG IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.ClientSecretValidator - Start client validation
2018-11-20 09:14:20,066 [244] DEBUG IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.BasicAuthenticationSecretParser - Start parsing Basic Authentication secret
2018-11-20 09:14:20,082 [244] DEBUG IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.PostBodySecretParser - Start parsing for secret in post body
2018-11-20 09:14:20,082 [244] DEBUG IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.PostBodySecretParser - No secret in post body found
2018-11-20 09:14:20,082 [244] DEBUG IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.X509CertificateSecretParser - Start parsing for X.509 certificate
2018-11-20 09:14:20,082 [244] DEBUG IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.X509CertificateSecretParser - client_id is not found in post body
2018-11-20 09:14:20,082 [244] INFO  IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.SecretParser - Parser found no secret
2018-11-20 09:14:20,082 [244] INFO  IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.ClientSecretValidator - No client secret found
2018-11-20 09:14:20,082 [244] INFO  IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.TokenEndpointController - End token request
2018-11-20 09:14:20,097 [244] INFO  IdentityServer3.Core.Results.TokenErrorResult - Returning error: invalid_client
```

If I specify `client_id` and `client_secret` as Basic Authentication  Header Identity server respond me with `unsupported_grant_type`.

```
2018-11-20 09:08:36,113 [323] INFO  IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.TokenEndpointController - Start token request
2018-11-20 09:08:36,144 [323] DEBUG IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.ClientSecretValidator - Start client validation
2018-11-20 09:08:36,144 [323] DEBUG IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.BasicAuthenticationSecretParser - Start parsing Basic Authentication secret
2018-11-20 09:08:36,144 [323] DEBUG IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.SecretParser - Parser found secret: BasicAuthenticationSecretParser
2018-11-20 09:08:36,144 [323] INFO  IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.SecretParser - Secret id found: gdpr_logger
2018-11-20 09:08:36,160 [323] DEBUG IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.SecretValidator - Secret validator success: HashedSharedSecretValidator
2018-11-20 09:08:36,160 [323] INFO  IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.ClientSecretValidator - Client validation success
2018-11-20 09:08:36,176 [323] INFO  IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.TokenRequestValidator - Start token request validation
2018-11-20 09:08:36,363 [323] ERROR IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.TokenRequestValidator - Grant type is missing.
 {
  "ClientId": "gdpr_logger",
  "ClientName": "GDPR Logger Client",
  "Raw": {}
}
2018-11-20 09:08:36,363 [323] INFO  IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.TokenEndpointController - End token request
2018-11-20 09:08:36,379 [323] INFO  IdentityServer3.Core.Results.TokenErrorResult - Returning error: unsupported_grant_type
```

As you can see in the last log in `Raw` it seems the data in post are not read/picked up from Identity Server.

I cannot understand what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My Server manager solved the problem.

The ModSecurity (in Plesk inside the Web Application Firewall) for a second level domain as in my case blocked the post data because is againt its rules.

Disabling or editing the rules solved the problem.